# C# - Automapper does not include related object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping, automapper

I know there are a lot of question about automapper.

My problem is that the related object did not mapped by Automapper, but the foreignId did.

```
 public class Location
 {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Company")]
        public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
        public Company Company { get; set; }
 }
```

Dto object:

```
 public class LocationDto
 {
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }      
        public int? CompanyId { get; set; } // this is 1 - which the Company.Id
        public CompanyDto Company { get; set; } // this is NULL
 }
```

Here the mapping configuration:

```
var configurator= new MapperConfigurationExpression();
configurator.CreateMap<LocationDto, Location>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Company, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Company));
configurator.CreateMap<Company, CompanyDto>();
configurator.CreateMap<CompanyDto, Company>();
Mapper.Initialize(configurator);
```

*If I know well, I did it in the right way, because I see this solution in a lot of post and tutorial.*

Here the called mapping command:

```
Task.FromResult(Mapper.Map<TSource>(DataLayer.Get<TDest>(id)));
```

I have no idea, why the `LocationDto.Company` always NULL (however the `LocationDto.CompanyId` prop always have value). **Do you know why that is null?**

I have tried without ForMember too, or with Member.Sourclist

```
configurator.CreateMap<LocationDto, Location>();
configurator.CreateMap<LocationDto, Location>(Member.SourceList);
```

But nothing helped.

Update: Companies

```
public class CompanyDto
    {
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public string Title{ get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int? CountryId { get; set; }
        //public CountryDto Country { get; set; }
        public int? CountyId{ get; set; }
        //public County County{ get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
   }
```

Here the Server part:

```
 public class Company
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public string Title{ get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Country")]
        public int? CountryId { get; set; }
        public Country Country { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("County")]
        public int? CountyId{ get; set; }
        public County County{ get; set; }

        public bool Active { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Haders> Haders { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Parts> Parts{ get; set; }

        public Company()
        {
            this.Active = true;
        }

        public Company(string title, string description)
        {
            this.Title = title;
            this.Description = description;
        }
}
```

Comment: Before seeking the AutoMapper configurations, are you sure `Location.Company` (note `Location`, not `LocationDto`, shortly the source from EF) is not null? What EF is this (EF6, EF Core)?

Comment: It is EF6, yes the Location is the source from EF.

Comment: Ok (for EF version), but the question was does it have value *before* mapping to dto or not? In other words, trying to figure out if the problem is in the mapping or in the source. e.g. can you confirm that `source.Location != null` when `dest.Location == null`?

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you for your patient! Yes, I can confirm. But the problem is that EF `Location.Company` null... but why? It seems EF did not attached the Company object to the `Location.Company` property.

Comment: Now, I know where is the problem the ServerEntityContext has the "wrong implementation" thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you forget this:

```
configurator.CreateMap<CompanyDto, Company>()
```

You need to add the Comany -> CompanyDto mapping to the configurations.

Comment: Thanks, I extended the mapping configurations source code here with it, I forget to copy here that mapping, but it does not matter, because the Company still Null.

Comment: And your destination class has a parameterless constructor? At this moment i have no more idea.

Comment: Yes, it has parameterless constructor.

Comment: Could you show the `Company` and the `CompanyDto` classes?

Comment: Yes, it is under the "Update: Companies" section.

Answer (score 0):

you must use `Include` Method for Load related object that it is Eager Loading.
you can use [AutoMapper.EF6](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.EF6) for doing this.

```
context.Locations.Where(x => x.Id == 1)
                 .Include(l => l.Company)
                 .ProjectToFirst<LocationDto>(Mapper.Configuration);
```